# AJAX data being sent to the wrong Django view

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I'm new to django and ajax so I've been working on a project to learn it. I have two buttons, one that adds a marker and one that deletes a marker.

Here is the views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def save(request):
    searchVar = request.POST.getlist('search[]')
    waypoint = Waypoint()
    waypoint.name = searchVar[0]
    waypoint.geometry = ('POINT(' + searchVar[2] + " " + searchVar[1] + ')')
    waypoint.save()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict(isOk=1)), content_type='application/json')

@csrf_exempt
def remove(request):
    objectID = request.POST.get('id')
    point = get_object_or_404(Point, pk = objectID)
    point.delete()
```

Here is the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('googlemaps.waypoints.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='waypoints-index'),
    url(r'', 'save', name='waypoints-save'),
    url(r'', 'remove', name='waypoints-remove'),
)
```

and here is the ajax from the js file

```
    $('#saveWaypoints').click(function () {
    var searchList = [search.name, search.geometry.location.lat(), search.geometry.location.lng()]
    $.ajax({
      url : "waypoints-save",
      type : "POST",
      data : { search : searchList }
    }, function (data) {
        if (data.isOk) {
            $('#saveWaypoints');
        } else {
            alert(data.message);
        }
    });
});
$('#removeWaypoints').click(function () {
  console.log(markerID);
    $.ajax({
      url : "waypoints-remove",
      type : "POST",
      data : { id : markerID }
    }, function (data) {
        if (data.isOk) {
            $('#removeWaypoints');
        } else {
            alert(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

The save button works fine, but when I click on the remove button I get this error in my console log

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/waypoints-remove 500 (Internal Server Error)

IndexError at /waypoints-remove
list index out of range

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/waypoints-remove
```

and this error in my server cmd

```
Internal Server Error: /waypoints-remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rnvitter\virtualenv4\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\rnvitter\virtualenv4\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rnvitter\virtualenv4\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rnvitter\virtualenv4\googlemaps\googlemaps\waypoints\views.py", line 23, in save
    waypoint.name = searchVar[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
2017-01-09 22:40:11,781 - ERROR - Internal Server Error: /waypoints-remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rnvitter\virtualenv4\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\rnvitter\virtualenv4\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rnvitter\virtualenv4\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rnvitter\virtualenv4\googlemaps\googlemaps\waypoints\views.py", line 23, in save
    waypoint.name = searchVar[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Which leads me to believe that the data from the remove button ajax call is being sent to my save view, does anyone know one?

Comment: In js file that you define urls will not work. You have to define ajax in html page with syntax of URL in ajax like :    url : "{% url 'waypoints-save' %}" that automatic create URL and your ajax will go in correct method and also use django latest way to define url in urls.py file without pattern https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `urls.py` file set up wrong. The first parameter is a regular expression to match a URL, so `^$` will match the root path. The name parameter is for getting the URL for a specific view, e.g. when you use the `reverse` function.

`^` indicates the beginning of a line and `$` indicates the end of a line. Together, with nothing in between, it will match an empty line.

To match another URL, such as `/waypoints-save/`, you would need to write another regex: `^/waypoints-save/$`. This will match the beginning of the line, followed by the characters `/waypoints-save/`, followed by the end of the line. To get your entire `urls.py` set up correctly, it should look like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('googlemaps.waypoints.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='waypoints-index'),
    url(r'^/waypoints-save/$', 'save', name='waypoints-save'),
    url(r'^/waypoints-remove/$', 'remove', name='waypoints-remove'),
)
```

Comment: that did the trick, I was pretty confused on how urls worked in django but this helped a lot thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have defined two URL entries that have the same regex.

```python
url(r'', 'save', name='waypoints-save'),
url(r'', 'remove', name='waypoints-remove'),
```

Since `/waypoints-remove` would match `r''` (a regex with nothing in it, therefore it will match anything), the first match wins, and the `save` method is executed. So the method you expected to run, `remove`, is not being run.